# error: use of undeclared identifier VS Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, undeclared-identifier

I am simply trying to compile a simple program including a .cpp and .h(.hpp for VS code Purposes)
Whenever I Put the implementation for the Constructor in the .hpp file and not include the .cpp, the code will compile. However, whenever i separate the Implementation into the .cpp file i get

```
error: use of undeclared identifier 'std' LinkedChar::(std::string s)
```

I have tried including headguards but use #pragma once, i still get the same error.
Here is my main.cpp

```
#include "LinkList.hpp"


int main()
{


  LinkedChar("h");


  return 0;
}
```

Here is my .hpp File

```
#pragma once
#include "LinkList.cpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

//Create a LinkList
class Node
{
  public:


  Node *next;
  char data; //The data will hold a character 
};

class LinkedChar
{   
  public:
  //LinkedChar(): head(NULL), tail(NULL){}
  LinkedChar(std::string s);


  private:
  Node* tail;
  Node* head;
};
```

my cpp file

```
#include "LinkList.hpp"

LinkedChar::LinkedChar(std::string s)
{

  int length = s.length();
  Node* temp = new Node;
  head = nullptr;



  if(length==1)//If there is only one letter
  {
     temp->data=s[0];
     head = temp;     
     tail = temp;
     temp->next = nullptr;
     std::cout<<temp->data;

  }

  else
  {
     for(int i = 1; i<length; i++)

     temp->data = s[i];
     temp->next = nullptr;
     tail = temp;

  }

}
```

Comment: 1) Don't `#include` .cpp files. 2) As is now, you have a mutual `#include` between the .hpp and .cpp.

Comment: Thanks, However When i try to run now i get a Permission denied error

Comment: If `LinkedChar::(std::string s)` is a real code in the error message then you show the irrelevant code.

Comment: use a build tool like Make or CMake or MSBuild

Answer (score 1):

Are you compiling the .cpp file? Your compilation command should look like `g++ -Iinclude/ main.cpp src/LinkedList.cpp`.

Also, don't include the .cpp file in your .hpp

Comment: Thanks, I took the include out, however i am still not able to compile. Is there anyway i can use the run button in VS code for c++11 or do i need to go through the terminal? It seems as if maybe something in a json file is not configured however I'm not sure how to configure that.

Comment: VS code always uses the terminal for compiling. You can definitely automatize this process. Check out [this useful page about configuring the debugger](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/launch-json-reference). It's not that difficult. Default values are usually pretty much good to go, just need a few tweaks. If you don't get it to work, maybe you can provide your tasks.json file.

Comment: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "LinkedChar::LinkedChar(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >)", referenced from:
      _main in mainfunc-403067.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64